# Should comma be specified after "I" in case of a sentence like I myname?

Tags: grammar, sentence

This question is about a confusion that I always had in my mind.

**My question:**
Suppose I am writing a sentence(for a speech or something like that) that actually begins like

```
I myname and the sentence continues.
```

My question is that should there be a comma after I?

Comment: "I, Charles, wrote this."  Needs two commas (assuming Charles is speaking and asserting he wrote this). See *apposition* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There should be a comma after I and after your name.

"I, Christine Lopez, am standing in front of you today to discuss about......."

Comment: Hello, Christine L., and welcome to English Language & Usage. I agree with your conclusion, but at this site we strive to include not just the yes/no answer to a yes/no question, but also an explanation of why the answer is yes (or no) and, if possible, a citation to an authoritative reference work that backs up our contention. Your answer will be stronger if you provide those additional things. Thanks!